# Android ArrayAdapter's getView weird behaviour when highlighting item

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom `DialogFragment` with a `ListView` in its layout with the purpose of being a single-choice list of items. I instantiate it with a `selectedItemId` parameter and I set it to the list's `ArrayAdapter` so I can highlight the latest selected item in the `getView()` method like this:

```
    public ItemSelectionListAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items, String selectedItemId) {
        super(context, RESOURCE);
        this.items = items;
        this.selectedItemId = selectedItemId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), RESOURCE, null);
        }

        Item item = items.get(position);

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;
        textView.setText(item.getName());

        String itemId = item.getId();

        Log.d(TAG, "Current item id: " + itemId);
        Log.d(TAG, "Selected item id: " + selectedItemId);

        if (itemId.equals(selectedItemId)) {
            textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.primaryColor));
            textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

The default item (when no item has been selected yet) is at position 0 so this image shows the expected view:

[image]

However, just when I select *other* item both are highlighted:

[image]

The code is really straightforward but the item at **position: 0** is always highlighted. I have checked already if `selectedId` is updated and yes, it is always the latest selected items's id. I also checked that all items have unique ids and yes they have:

This is de log for the first time the dialog shows:

```
06-20 14:26:37.677 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: getCount() -> 6
06-20 14:26:37.677 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: -2
06-20 14:26:37.678 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: -2
06-20 14:26:37.678 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: 3
06-20 14:26:37.678 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: -2
06-20 14:26:37.678 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: 4
06-20 14:26:37.679 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: -2
06-20 14:26:37.679 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: 5
06-20 14:26:37.679 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: -2
06-20 14:26:37.680 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: 6
06-20 14:26:37.680 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: -2
06-20 14:26:37.680 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: 7
06-20 14:26:37.680 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: -2
```

And this is another time after clicking on some item:

```
06-20 14:28:24.759 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: getCount() -> 6
06-20 14:28:24.760 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: -2
06-20 14:28:24.760 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: 4
06-20 14:28:24.760 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: 3
06-20 14:28:24.761 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: 4
06-20 14:28:24.761 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: 4
06-20 14:28:24.761 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: 4
06-20 14:28:24.762 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: 5
06-20 14:28:24.762 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: 4
06-20 14:28:24.762 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: 6
06-20 14:28:24.763 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: 4
06-20 14:28:24.763 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Current item id: 7
06-20 14:28:24.763 7860-7860/xxx D/ADAPTER: Selected item id: 4
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Once an item is clicked, its id is stored in the activity (it will be the next `selectedItemId`) and the dialog is destroyed. So the adapter is creating every time for one item to be selected.

**EDIT 2:**
This is the important code of the dialog, where I instantiate the adapter and set it to the `ListView` each time the dialog is created.

```
    @Bind(R.id.item_list)
    protected ListView list;

    private String selectedItemId;
    private List<Item> items;

    public static ItemSelectionDialog newInstance(String selectedItemId) {
        ItemSelectionDialog dialog = new ItemSelectionDialog();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_ITEM_ID, selectedItemId);
        dialog.setArguments(args);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        selectedItemId = getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID);
        items = getItemsFromDataBase();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_item_selection, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        // Here I instantiate the adapter with a different selectedItemId each time
        list.setAdapter(new ItemSelectionListAdapter(getContext(), items, selectedItemId));

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(view)
            .create();
    }

    // This is a normal OnItemClickListener attached to the ListView
    @OnItemClick(R.id.item_list)
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        // Here I store the ID in the host activity, which implements a custom "OnItemSelectedListener"
        listener.onItemSelected(items.get(position));
        dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have code for selection, but not for removing that selection. where is else part? first time 0th position item will be highlighted, next time other selected one but you're not removing selection from previous one that is at 0th position

```
if (itemId.equals(selectedItemId)) {
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.primaryColor));
        textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
    }else{
 textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.black));
        textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
 }
```

Comment: The list is in a dialog that is destroyed and recreated each time, so it is not necessary any *unselecting* code. Sorry I should specify it.

Comment: each time by default you're taking 0th position selected then selected position that's why 0th position is always selected

Comment: When the app starts, the selectedItemId is -2, which is the default item. That is only for the **first time** the dialog is shown, when no item has previously been selected.

Comment: If your hypothesis was, every time I clicked on an item it should be highlighted as well, so in the end **every item would be blue and bold**, but that is not the case. The only highlighted item is the last I clicked **plus** the one an position 0.

Comment: two of your logs mentioned above, for selected position 2 and 4, displays 0th and 2nd, 0th and 4th respectively ?

Comment: creating a new adapter, new dialog is heavy on resources. when you can re-use same dialog and list by just calling notifydatasetchange. according to your code each time user select something, dialog dismiss and re-appear, that isn't a good user experience either

Comment: Exactly the same UX that a spinner with dialog mode. Maybe I could save the dialog in an activity's field but then it would be occupying memory that the user probably won't use again, that why I am recreating it. Anyway I don't see how that would be a solution for my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are recreating each time the listView of the dialog
add another boolean to Item class, by default it would be false, then
you should add onItemClick to the listView and update your items data structure 
according to the position of onItemClick callback, make sure to initialize all the items selected field to false before you update the selected item in items data structure.
The last thing you will need to do just add what @Pr38y commented but with a little change instead of using

```
if(itemId.equals(selectedItemId))
```

use this one:

```
if(item.isSelected())
```

Comment: I know already which item is selected thanks to the id so adding a boolean would be redundant.

Comment: What is selectedItemId? you could also save just the selected position
of the selected item inside of your adapter

Comment: Again, the adapter is lost once the dialog is destroyed, the only thing I save is the selectedItemId, which is the ID of the last item that has been selected in the dialog.

Comment: Ok, so you will need to save it in a field from where you are opening the dialog, before the dialog is dismissed you will need to update the screen(activity/fragment) on the updated selected position, you could use a listener to accomplish this and override the onDismiss or before calling dismiss(); from onItemClick of the listView

Comment: It is already done like that. I did not want to put all the code but I will for the sake of our understanding. I put the AlertDialog code and the adapter constructor, I think is enough but tell me otherwise.

Comment: I assume after selecting an item your are dismiss the dialog, I had similar problem, after setting the selected position I just set the list adapter with the new position and did notifyDataSetChanged, after it I just did getView().postDelayed for lets say 200 msec and only then I just dismissed the dialog, unfortunately there is no callback after  notifyDataSetChanged completed